# How to disable Root Access, to VPS, via SSH?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, root, putty

I run a VPS, on a Linux Server, with CentOS 7 (64 bits) being the chosen Operating System.

I have recently wiped the VPS, so it only has a clean install of Plesk Onyx at the moment.  I would now like to disable root access to the VPS, via SSH, prior to setting up domains and emails.

To achieve this, I gained SSH access, via the PuTTY Terminal.  Using the Nano Text Editor, I entered the following Command Line:

```
# nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

This opened up the correct file, where I then changed the `#PermitRootLogin` entry from 'yes' to 'no'; as per the following screenshot:

[image]

I was able to save and exit the file.  I also was able to see that the changes were indeed saved, upon accessing the file again.

I am aware that in order for such changes to take place, the SSH Service needs restarting.  To do this, I have tried the following command lines (Individually):

```
# service ssh reload
# sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
# sudo systemctl restart sshd
# sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
```

None of the above command lines, confirmed whether or not SSH was restarted.  Regardless, I am still able to log into SSH using the root credentials.

Is anyone able to identify where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many configuration files commented lines show you the default values, like in your sshd_config file:

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

You need to change to **no** AND delete **#** to un-comment the line

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

As for the systemctl, and many other commands, if it doesn't return anything it means that the command was successful

Comment: Bang on.  I just removed the hashtag.  With that being said, I never had to remove the hashtag, when using Debian.